# FadeOut Content load and show content

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to simply show the content after load not fadeIn how is it possible?

```
$(function() {
  $('.hovers').click(function(event) {
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    window.location.hash = target;
    $.ajax({
        url: target,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#allcontent')
                .fadeOut('slow', function() {
                    $(this).html(data).fadeIn('slow');
                });
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

maybe i use .show() ?

Thanks for help

Comment: Didn't you try it? i.e. using `.show()`

Comment: it don't work :/ Yes of course..

Comment: @KevinBowersox - Yes, i think so. But instead of just `show()`, you probably need something like `.css('opacity', 1).show()`

Comment: @Anton - Perhaps for the effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fadeIn 0 , which happens immediately

```
$(this).html(data).fadeIn(0);
```

also you might want to do this

```
$(this).html(data).delay(2000).fadeIn(0);
```

adding a delay of 2 seconds or however much you want, and then show immediately

Answer (score 2):

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#allcontent').html(data).show();
}
```